# How to mock TableResult queried from Bigquery

Tags: spring, kotlin, google-bigquery

I want to integrate BigQuery SDK to our service. Everything works well but I encountered some problems when mock TableResult during writing test.

BigQuery SDK is integrated as follows:

```
@Service
class BigQueryDataService(
    @Value("\${application.big-query.project-id}")
    val projectId: String,
    @Value("\${application.big-query.dataset-name}")
    val datasetName: String,
    @Value("\${application.big-query.table-name}")
    val tableName: String,
) {
    fun doQuery(query: String): TableResult? {
        val bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().service
        val queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query).build()
        return bigquery.query(queryConfig)
    }
}
```

Could you give some suggestion on mocking TableResult in integration test?